# Why don't DateTime.ToString("R") and DateTime.TryParseExact round trip?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I'm implementing conditional requests in a Web service.  The backend can easily retrieve the last modified date of an entity, so I'm sending Last-Modified and getting back If-Modified-Since.  The [RFC for HTTP Dates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) specifies a format that is the same as the ["R" format specifier in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#RFC1123).

The problem is that `DateTime.ToString("R")` formats the date correctly, but passing `"R"` to `ParseExact` doesn't read the time zone back (there is a "Round trip" specifier, `"O"`, but it's not in the format I need).  Here's an example in LinqPad:

```
DateTime lastModified = new DateTime(2015, 10, 01, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
string lastModifiedField = lastModified.ToString("R"); // Thu, 01 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT
DateTime ifModifiedSince = DateTime.ParseExact(
   lastModifiedField, "R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

ifModifiedSince.Kind.Dump(); // Unspecified
```

I can certainly use methods on the parsed `DateTime` to force it into the format I want, but how can I get the framework to use the data that's already there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I stumbled across the reference source that explains this, hence asking and answering my own question.

The [source to datetimeparse.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,3745) indicates that this is a bug that can't be fixed for compatibility.

```
// The "r" and "u" formats incorrectly quoted 'GMT' and 'Z', respectively.  We cannot
// correct this mistake for DateTime.ParseExact for compatibility reasons, but we can 
// fix it for DateTimeOffset.ParseExact as DateTimeOffset has not been publically released
// with this issue.
```

So the code this comment precedes is called by both DateTime.ParseExact and DateTimeOffset.ParseExact, and suggests in effect that DateTimeOffset.ParseExact is more correct.  Indeed, according to the documentation on [choosing between DateTime and DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> These uses for DateTimeOffset values are much more common than those
>   for DateTime values. As a result, DateTimeOffset should be considered
>   the default date and time type for application development.

Therefore the ideal solution is to switch to DateTimeOffset, but if you still need DateTime:

```
DateTime lastModified = new DateTime(2015, 10, 01, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
string lastModifiedField = lastModified.ToString("R");
DateTimeOffset ifModifiedSinceOffset = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
   lastModifiedField, "R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime ifModifiedSince = ifModifiedSinceOffset.UtcDateTime;

ifModifiedSince.Kind.Dump(); // Utc
```

Which correctly identifies the time zone as GMT/UTC, and thus sets the correct property on the DateTime.

Comment: Yes, this is good - except note that the final `Kind` will *always* be `Utc`, since you obtained it from `.UtcDateTime`.  But at least the parsing is correct.  You'll be interested to also observe that `DateTime.Parse` *does* work - at least it does when you pass `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind`.  It's only `DateTime.ParseExact` that doesn't.

Comment: Of course - it would be preferred to use ISO8601 instead of this horrendous format, but still - good catch!

Comment: Also, you might want to log this at https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues - seems silly not to fix it.

Comment: @MattJohnson, the comment says they cannot fix it for compatibility purposes, and I see their point.  And I agree that this format is silly (why include the day of the week in a field meant for computers to read) but I was trying to follow the IRC precisely because it's a luxury to have a spec every once in a while. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I disagree with keeping this bug around.  I logged it here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1757

Comment: I guess there's (hopefully) not a lot of code out there that "needs" this to be broken.  Thanks for filing!